# What symbol means continues irrationally?

Tags: notation, decimal-expansion

Typically we use an ellipsis (...) to show that a number continues on; e.g.:

```
1/3 = 0.33333...
```

Even in the English language, it is used to indicate that something continues on and on, like so:

> The team just kept scoring goal after goal after goal...

But what if a number continues irrationally? My favorite constant, `e`, is often written like so:

```
e: 2.718281...
```

Even in wikipedia, continuation of our beloved Pi is shown to continue on with an elipsis

```
Pi: 3.1415927...
```

Wouldn't it make sense to use a different symbol? Say, a tilde:

```
Pi: 3.1415927~
```

Is there a symbol in existence to indicate that a number continues irrationally?

Comment: Well, you'd need yet another symbol for something like [Euler's number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Mascheroni_constant) the irrationality of which is unknown.

Comment: More broadly, the standard notation does not suggest (at least not to me) that the remaining string follows a pattern.  If you want to indicate the full decimal for, say, $\frac 13$ you should use a bar, as in $\frac 13=.\overline 3$  Thus we can write $\frac 17=.142857\dots$ to indicate a numerical approximation or $\frac 17=.\overline {142857}$ to provide the full decimal.

Comment: This seems to be one of the few situations in which mathematicians rely on colloquial understanding to differentiate between contexts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the ellipsis *is* the symbol for "continues irrationally", or at least for "continues, not necessarily rationally".

If you wish to indicate that a decimal "continues rationally", you do so with an overbar:

$$\dfrac 1 3 = 0.\overline{3}$$

$$\dfrac{4}{33}=0.\overline{12}$$